# Offset in battery icon in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons

On my [Lenovo Yoga 500 14-ISK](http://www3.lenovo.com/in/en/laptops/yoga/yoga-500-series/Lenovo-Yoga-500-14ISK/p/88YG5000648), I have a strange (maybe unimportant or stupid, but it bothers me all the same) problem. The battery icon in the taskbar displays the battery inside with a slight offset (running Windows 10 1607)

Thus, the battery icon looks like this:

[image]

When it should be looking like this:

[image]

Could this be a bug <s>or possibly a manufacturer customization</s>? <s>Or is it because I'm using a full-hd display and it looks like the latter on a non-full-hd display?</s> For some reason, I find this really distracting, being used to the symmetric icon.

**EDIT:**

Weirdly enough, since I was paying much closer attention to the icon after asking this question, I just noticed the icon flip to the symmetric one for a few minutes, before going back to the original! I've updated the image above. Rules out some possibilities!

Comment: Looks more like a design flaw to me than anything, although I am having trouble finding this issue online anywhere.  I am leaning towards your hunch as this may be related to your display settings and specs.

Comment: @CheesusCrust, the display settings seems to ruled out, now that I know it sometimes displays the icon correctly. I guess its just a design flaw in this case...

Comment: As long as it is still accurate in its intended use.  Although, keep us updated if you figure something out.  I am curious now as well.